Быстрая перерисовка графика QWT
Каким образом можно быстрее перерисовывать график, по сравнению с void QwtPlot::setAutoReplot (bool tf = true)
По наблюдениям, данный метод отрабатывает с некоторой задержкой, имеются ли ещё какие-нибудь варианты обновления содержимого объекта QwtPlot в рантайме?
